# Create files on remote hosts via ssh and sudo

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

## Conditions

- h1, h2, and h3 are three Linux hosts that have joined the same Active Directory domain
- Account A and B are both AD account
- B can SSH into all hosts with no password required (Kerberos authentication is setup), and sudo as A (`sudoer` is setup so it can run ALL command without password) on each host
- A can’t SSH into these hosts directly
- `/local/path/` exist on all hosts
- f1 and f2 are created under `/local/path/` on h1, and these files are only readable by A
- These files can contain multiple lines, double quotes, $

## Target

- Create f1 and f2 on h2 and h3 with the same content

## My incomplete solution

I come up with the following script, however it has some problems: `""` and `$` will disappear

1. Could you help make my script work as expected
2. Is there a better way to achieve my goal?

```bash
# src and dest should actually be the same (but on different hosts)
# Since we are doing the test on localhost, they are set to different directories (only accessible by testuser, i.e. account A)
SRC_DIR=/home/testuser
DEST_DIR=/var/tmp/testuser


# For demo purpose. In reality, it should be an array of hosts, i.e. h2, h3
HOSTS=(localhost)
FILES=(f1 f2)
declare -A FILE_TO_CONTENT=([f1]="`sudo -i -u testuser cat /home/testuser/f1`" [f2]="`sudo -i -u testuser cat /home/testuser/f2`")

for h in ${HOSTS[@]}
do
  for f in ${FILES[@]}
  do
    file_content=${FILE_TO_CONTENT[$f]}
    echo "$file_content"  # The output looks normal
    ssh $h "echo \"${file_content}\" | sudo -i -u testuser tee $DEST_DIR/$f "  # Double quotes are removed, $dollar disappears
    echo ""  # Separate output for different files
  done
done
```

The content of `f1` and `f2`

```
# f1
f1-line 1
f1-line 2
f1-line 3 with "double quote"
f1-line 4 with 'single quote'
f1-line 5 with special char: #hash, $dollar

# f2
f2-line 1
f2-line 2
```

The output after I run my script (and the output file under `/var/tmp/testuser` also don't have `""` and `$`)

```
f1-line 1
f1-line 2
f1-line 3 with "double quote"
f1-line 4 with 'single quote'
f1-line 5 with special char: #hash, $dollar
f1-line 1
f1-line 2
f1-line 3 with double quote
f1-line 4 with 'single quote'
f1-line 5 with special char: #hash, 

f2-line 1
f2-line 2
f2-line 1
f2-line 2
```

Comment: try `ssh $h 'echo "'"${file_content}"'" | sudo -i -u testuser tee '"$DEST_DIR/$f"`, so the local shell will not touch them since you used double quotes around the remote command

Comment: Why do you need `sudo`'s option `-i`? I would not put the files' contents into a variable. In the loop you can do `sudo -u testuser cat "SRC_DIR/$f" | ssh "$h" sudo -u testuser tee "$DEST_DIR/$f"` or with GNU `tar` and only a loop over the hosts `sudo -u testuser tar -C "$SRC_DIR" c f1 f2 | ssh "$h" sudo -u testuser tar -C "$DEST_DIR" x`. Repeatedly reading the same files will probably be fast due to caching.

Comment: @Bodo, thanks it works!

Comment: I copied my comment into an answer with a few improvements. Which command did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not put the files' contents into a variable.

In the loop you can do

```
sudo -u testuser cat "SRC_DIR/$f" | ssh "$h" sudo -u testuser tee "$DEST_DIR/$f"
```

```
# src and dest should actually be the same (but on different hosts)
# Since we are doing the test on localhost, they are set to different directories (only accessible by testuser, i.e. account A)
SRC_DIR=/home/testuser
DEST_DIR=/var/tmp/testuser


# For demo purpose. In reality, it should be an array of hosts, i.e. h2, h3
HOSTS=(localhost)
FILES=(f1 f2)

for h in "${HOSTS[@]}"
do
  for f in "${FILES[@]}"
  do
    sudo -u testuser cat "SRC_DIR/$f" | ssh "$h" sudo -u testuser tee "$DEST_DIR/$f"
    echo ""  # Separate output for different files
  done
done
```

or with GNU `tar` and only a loop over the hosts

```
sudo -u testuser tar -C "$SRC_DIR" c "${FILES[@]}" | ssh "$h" sudo -u testuser tar -C "$DEST_DIR" x
```

```
# src and dest should actually be the same (but on different hosts)
# Since we are doing the test on localhost, they are set to different directories (only accessible by testuser, i.e. account A)
SRC_DIR=/home/testuser
DEST_DIR=/var/tmp/testuser


# For demo purpose. In reality, it should be an array of hosts, i.e. h2, h3
HOSTS=(localhost)
FILES=(f1 f2)

for h in "${HOSTS[@]}"
do
  sudo -u testuser tar -C "$SRC_DIR" c "${FILES[@]}" | ssh "$h" sudo -u testuser tar -C "$DEST_DIR" x
done
```

Repeatedly reading the same files will probably be fast due to caching.